# Symfony2: Collection of dropdown select lists for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

**The objective:**

Having a many-to-many relation be displayed as a dynamic list of select inputs(single choice dropdown list)

User arrives on page with a single select field (multiple = false) populated with persisted entities and add/remove buttons. By clicking the add button, a new select field with the same options appears below the first, which adds a new entry in the M2M relation. By clicking remove the field disappears and the entry should be removed.

**The model:**

Two entities: User & Manager. A User has exactly one "special" Manager and unlimited normal Managers.
Managers manage unlimited users.To model this I have created two relationships for which the user is the "owner" (not sure how to translate this)

- ManyToOne specialManager
- ManyToMany normalManagers

I haven't created a many to many relationship with attribute "special" because the requirement is exactly one special manager and I wasn't sure if Symfony/Doctrine would cause problems down the line.

**What I have:**

- I  can display a multiple select field with the existing entities using Entity field type, as per the documentation. Functionally this is what I need, visually it is not.
- I can also use the Collection field type to display a single text field, and add or remove more with JS, as per the documentation. Visually this is what I need, but The text fields (entity attribute) need to be replaced by choice field.

**The question:**

Before I continue digging, is there a simple way to achieve this list of select tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who may eventually need a dynamic list of select fields:

I initially solved this issue by detaching the field(s) in event listeners, and handling the display/submission manually in the controller.

However I wasn't satisfied with this clunky solution and when I encountered the same need I used a second solution: creating an intermediary entity xxxChoice (in this case ManagerChoice) which is Mto1 inversed related to User and Mto1 related to Manager. Then by creating a ManagerChoiceType form with "Manager" entity field type I was able to easily display my collection of dropdown select lists.